# Como utilizar o orderByKey e EqualTo do Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Preciso buscar no meu database, qual o "FLOOR KEY" que é "main".

Os dados que eu tenho é seguinte:

> **this._userID** = ALIANSCE
>
> **this._mapID** = NOME DO MAPA QUE FOI CLICADO NO
> MARKER DO GOOGLE MAPS
>
> O que eu não tenho é o nome do "FLOOR" que eu preciso encontrar de
> acordo com o que eu falei acima.

**Eu recebo a seguinte notificação no console:**

> util.js:189 FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Your data
> will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding
> ".indexOn": "floorType" at
> /users/Aliansce/MAPS/ViaParqueShopping/FLOORS/B30 to your security
> rules for better performance.

**O meu código é o seguinte:**

```
static AsyncQueryMainFloorMap(mapID){
        const GOOGLE_MAPS_STATIC_CLASS = GoogleMaps;

        this._userID = "Aliansce";
        this._mapID = mapID;
 
        this._mapFloorROOT = this.FirebaseInstance.ref('users/' + this._userID + '/MAPS/' + this._mapID).child('FLOORS');
        this._mapFloorROOT.once('child_added').then((mapFloorSnapshot) => {
            this._floorROOT =  this.FirebaseInstance.ref('users/' + this._userID + '/MAPS/' + this._mapID + '/FLOORS/').child('' + mapFloorSnapshot.key + '/');
            this._floorROOT.orderByChild('floorType').equalTo('main').once('child_added').then((e) => {
                console.log(e.key)
            });

            
        }) .catch((error) => {
            console.warn("error: " + error);
            // TODO
        });
  
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Também gastei umas horitas a tentar perceber o que estava mal e porquê esta mensagem. Adicione a regra no teu local de regras:

```
{
   "rules": {
   ...,
   ...,
     "nome_tabela_ou_colecao": {
       ".indexOn": "floorType"
   }
  }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.